# ClassTag causes Spark to serialize object

Tags: scala, serialization, apache-spark

The following code fails with a `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable` exception:

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

class Foo[T](rdd: RDD[T])(implicit kt: ClassTag[T]) {
  def die() {
    rdd.map(_ => Array[T]()).count()
  }
}

val x = sc.parallelize(Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
val foo = new Foo(x)
foo.die()
```

since `Foo` is not serializable.  Why is the functional literal passed to `map` causing `Foo` to get serialized when it just refers to the implicit parameter `ClassTag`?  How do I get around it?  This works when `Foo` works over `Int` instead of `T`.  My actual code is trying to `toArray` but it is the same problem.  Thanks!

edit: I'm running this with spark-shell.  Here's the serialization stack:

```
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: $iwC$$iwC$Foo, value: $iwC$$iwC$Foo@4ce1292a)
    - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$Foo$$anonfun$die$1, name: $outer, type: class $iwC$$iwC$Foo)
    - object (class $iwC$$iwC$Foo$$anonfun$die$1, <function1>)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:312)
    ... 56 more
```

Comment: Can you please add `-Dsun.io.serialization.extendedDebugInfo=true` to app when you submit it, and show the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't specific to `implicit` or `ClassTag`.  The following works:

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

class Foo[T](rdd: RDD[T])(implicit kt: ClassTag[T]) {
  def die() {
    val localKt = kt
    rdd.map(_ => Array[T]()(localKt)).count()
  }
}

val x = sc.parallelize(Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
val foo = new Foo(x)
foo.die()
```